# resampling (downscaling) 2D vector following another 1d/2d vector

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, time-series

In Earth Sciences we face a common issue. Sometimes we have data that represent any given parameter sampled at different intervals in time which are not necessarily evenly spaced.

For example we have time vs temperature, but the time spacing between temperature readings is not evenly spaced. Now, many times we need to compare this time series with another time series (for the same or any other parameter, e.g. humidity) that has been sampled at different time intervals and also unevenly spaced.

What I want to do in Python is to downscale the series with more data points (temperature) interpolating the data and resampling it to the same time intervals as the second time series (humidity in this case).

Programatically in Python I have 2 x 2D arrays with different lenghts and I want to resample the longest array to the same intervals as the shorter array, interpolating linearly when necessary to create the corresponding data points.

Is there any function or library in python that can do that in a simple way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for SciPy's interpolation:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

I've adapted the example to work for points that are not evenly spaced.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, num=11, endpoint=True) + np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=2, size=11)
y = np.cos(-x**2/9.0)
f = interp1d(x, y)
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

xmin = min(x)
xmax = max(x)
xnew = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, num=101, endpoint=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
plt.legend(['data', 'linear', 'cubic'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is useful but not quite what I am looking for. See my comment below.

Comment: I can't solve your exact problem unless you include demonstration code. You can't apply my example to your problem?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to paste a picture which is self-illustrative but since my rep is too low I cannot do it. Will try to edit my post with pseudo-code.